# How to protect site so that only clients can see during construction?

Tags: php, security

I'm writing a site for a few friends who don't know how to code.  I don't want to write on my localhost because I want them to be able to see the site's progress.  I would like to write on the site itself.  How would I go about setting up a simple password system so that only they are able to see the site?  Although this isn't secure at all, this is the best I could think of:

site.com/index.php:

```
<body>
    <form type="POST" action="/redirect.php">
       <input type="text" name="textbox">
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
</body>
```

site.com/redirect.php:

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['textbox'] == 'password123'){
      //redirect to site.com/actualSite/index.php
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: What webserver are you running? This is usually accomplished by using [HTTP authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking).

Comment: You could build an ip whitelist

Comment: Also, never use == for string comparison in PHP. It doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @ant - What do you mean?  It simply is not a literal comparison... Would work fine in this case...

Comment: @Lix If the the password it's checking against 'looks numerical' then it will accept infinitely many incorrect passwords as correct. For example, if ($_POST['textbox'] == '123'), would accept passwords like '   123' or '0x7b'.

Comment: @ant - Yes - you are correct about the technicalities of literal comparison - but you have to be more specific.  In this case - you could have mentioned possible problems with seemingly numeric passwords.  Saying `"It doesn't do what you want"` is not explaining the entire picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two quick and dirty suggestions for you.

#### Limit by IP -

```
$ipWhiteList = array(
    'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX', // teammate1,
    'YY.YYY.YYY.YYY', // teammate2
);
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$ipWhiteList)){
    die('Access Denied!');
}
```

#### Limit by a password in `$_GET` parameter -

```
$predefined_password = "4815162342";
if ($_GET['pass'] != $predefined_password){
  die('Access Denied!');
}
```

Now all your teammates have to do is append the password to their URL like so -

`https://myCoolNewSite.com?pass=4815162342`

Please know that these are not extremely complex methods of securing a URL but for your needs. to temporarily limit access during development - they might just be enough.  Quick and dirty ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simple method I used once was to have a complicated URL that would set a cookie.
And then when someone visits the "secret" site you check for that cookie, if it's there you show it if it's not you return a 404.

You can also check for IP (although that is a bit more of a pain).

You can also use [.htpasswd](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml) to protect the whole directory with a password. This would be the most common and easy method.